# Calculation puzzle 007

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

What is x?

```
76   26   24   24   30   x
```

There is a connection between these numbers. Based on that connection, find x.
Possible answer is

> 18

Source: This question was asked in YTUYOS 2017 (Yildiz Technical University exam for International students in 2017) in booklet A, question no: 53.

Comment: If there is only one possible answer, I would say: 18.

Comment: @FlorianF, can you elaborate, please? That answer is true, but how? Thanks.

Comment: You gave the answer.  Basically you are asking a multiple-choice question with only one choice.

Comment: add the digits of the first number 7+6=13 and multiply by 2 to get 26. Continue with that logic by multiplying with 3, 4, 5... I'm sure, this is according to FlorianF logic as well.

Comment: @FlorianF Thanks for downvote, but I'm tired of explaining this type of exam. It may sound strange but these are the questions asked in university entrance exam for international students in Turkey. These types of questions should not take more than 2 minutes to solve and generally they do have only one answer. In case they have more than one then the question is cancelled. Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasL that is the answer. I got it. Thank you so much. Can you please write your logic below so that I can accept it as a correct answer. I feel very happy now. Thank you so much.

Comment: @garakchy No downvote from me.  The question looks good.  It is just unusual that you give the answer straight away.

Comment: @FlorianF the universities sometimes provide the answer to all questions after the exam. The correct answer was given in the booklet, and I added it here in order to help anyone who tries to solve the question. It was correctly solved by ThomasL. I'm very proud of this community. Thanks everyone.

Comment: an upvote from my side, it's a good question,

Comment: @ThomasL thank you, sir. Appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an explanation for 18 as a solution:

> add the digits of the first number 7+6=13 and multiply by 2 to get 26. Continue with that logic by multiplying with 3, 4, 5. The last step gives the solution $(3+0)*6=18$

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the answer can be

> 96

Because

> Consider the polynomial $p(x) = (25x^4-242x^3+839x^2-1222x+912)/12$. We get $p(0)=76, p(1)=26, p(2)=24, p(3)=24, p(4)=30$. The next number is $p(5)=96$.

Of course

> this is a bit too generic answer which is not usually allowed, but I'm posting it here because the polynomial coefficients are not too ugly, and the result is an integer of reasonable magnitude (if the resulting answer was e.g. $-\frac{10894}{349}$ I would not even post it here). Moreover, since it is a *technical* university exam, it's reasonable to expect a somewhat technical solution to the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this question should not take more than two minutes. Solution should be easy, but one needs to find a connection, a method that applies to all numbers. That algorithm leads to the x.